# Tracing thread creation points for debugging

Tags: c++

I've come to love lambdas, and a while ago I wrote a simple wrapper which takes a lambda and starts it on a new thread.

```
//
// Starts a task on a separate thread, when passed a lambda expression
//
template<typename T>
smart_ptrs::w32handle StartTask(T f)
{
    // Make a copy of the task on the heap
    T* pTask = new T(f);

    // Create a new thread to service the task
    smart_ptrs::w32handle hThread(::CreateThread(
        NULL, 
        0, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)& detail::start_task_proc<T>, 
        (LPVOID) pTask, 
        NULL, 
        NULL)); 

    // If the caller ignores this rc, the thread handle will simply close and the
    // thread will continue in fire-and-forget fashion.
    return hThread;
}
```

**NOTE**: Yes I know this doesn't really need a template and could happily use `std::function`.  I've posted it this way because it matches more complicated (async queue) versions I have which do have to be templates.

The end result is a function which is very easy to use in parallel algorithms etc.  However a problem arises if you start to use such a function extensively.  Because the threads created all appear to come from the same rather generic function it can become difficult to tell where in the code they were started.  It's usually possible to work out from the context of what they're doing but it's not as easy as it used to be when using an explicit thread function.  Does anyone have a good method of tagging such threads so that they're easier to debug?

Comment: If you are using lambdas, you seem to have C++11 support. But if you have that, why would you use that clumsy WinAPI thread stuff instead of C++11's `std::thread`?

Comment: Not answering the question itself, but are you familiar with [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)?

Comment: OT: Using template argument deduction over std::function is more flexible all around, and potentially more efficient (not applicable here, I wager).

Comment: @ArneMertz I have to use the VC2010 compiler.  It doesn't have `std::thread`.   (Although VC2012 does)

Comment: @Angew - Yes, but I don't have access to it with this version of my compiler.

Comment: @Benj so what about using `boost::thread`?

Comment: @ArneMertz - Not an option unfortunately, I'm banned from using boost :-(  That being said, would that actually solve my problem?  How easy are boost threads to identify in the debugger?

Comment: You can add template parameter to `StartTask`, which will work as a tag. You will at least know that thread started in `StartTask<Lambda, struct Something>`.

Comment: @zch Is it possible to do this and then not use the tag in the code?  Won't the compiler complain?

Comment: I was thinking about explicit tagging - `StartTask<class OperationDelta>([](){ ... })`. But you can also use preprocessor macro to tag with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: If you are using lambdas, `start_task_proc` will call that lambda, so you should see the lambda's `operator()` in the call stack - and the call of `StartTask` should be right where the lambda is defined. So clicking on the lambda's `operator()` in the debugger should lead you to the callsite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the code, you'll have threads that have a `start_task_proc` somewhere in their callstack that call their function object. You could modify that function to take a pointer to a "task info" structure, rather than the bare function object. You could stuff whatever information you like into that information object, e.g. line numbers and filenames of where you created the task:

```
template <class T>
struct TaksInfo {
  T func;
  unsigned line;
  char const* file;

  TaskInfo(T&& t, unsigned l, char const* f)
    : func(std::move(t), line(l), file(f) {}
};


template<typename T>
smart_ptrs::w32handle StartTask(T f, unsigned line, char const* file)
{
    // Make a copy of the task on the heap
    auto pTask = new TaskInfo<T>(f, line, file);

    // Create a new thread to service the task
    smart_ptrs::w32handle hThread(::CreateThread(
        NULL, 
        0, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)& detail::start_task_proc<T>, 
        (LPVOID) pTask, 
        NULL, 
        NULL)); 

    // If the caller ignores this rc, the thread handle will simply close and the
    // thread will continue in fire-and-forget fashion.
    return hThread;
}

#define START_TASK(f) StartTask(f, __LINE__, __FILE__)

template <class T>
DWORD start_task_proc(LPVOID lpParameter) {
  auto pTask = (TaskInfo<T>*) lpParameter;
  return pTask->func();
}


//use:
int main() {
  auto threadHandle = START_TASK(([]() -> DWORD { std::cout << "foo\n"; return 42;} ));
}
```

If you now inspect `pTask` in `start_task_proc` you can see `file` and `line` wich can tell you where the task was started.
Of course you could avoid the `TaskInfo` structure and make the information just a template parameter of `start_task_proc`:

```
template <class T, unsigned Line, char const* File>
DWORD start_task_proc(LPVOID lpParameter) { /* as you have it */)

template<unsigned Line, char const* File, typename T> //use T last fur type deduction
smart_ptrs::w32handle StartTask(T f)
{
    // Make a copy of the task on the heap
    auto pTask = new T(std::move(f));

    // Create a new thread to service the task
    smart_ptrs::w32handle hThread(::CreateThread(
        NULL, 
        0, 
        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)& detail::start_task_proc<T, Line, File>,   //!!!
        (LPVOID) pTask, 
        NULL, 
        NULL)); 

    // If the caller ignores this rc, the thread handle will simply close and the
    // thread will continue in fire-and-forget fashion.
    return hThread;
}

#define START_TASK(f) StartTask<__LINE__, __FILE__>(f)
```

Comment: I like this, relatively little overhead too.